# How to exclude a tag from css inheritance (:not is not working)

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I have an  that I want to exclude from the general inheritance of the css.
I have added ":not" on the css but it still passes the inheritance on the child.
Also I have added both a new id and a new class and still doesn't follow non of them.

HTML code
 `<a id="epLogin" href="#" class="pLogin" > GET ON TOP! </a>`

CSS formating

```
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus,
#Mainbody div.tags a:hover,
#Mainbody a:not(#epLogin) { 
    color: #3498db; 
}

#epLogin {
margin-top: 0px;
background: #00B5F7;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
right: 20px;
height: 38px;
padding: 0 18px;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
line-height: 39px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't prevent element to inherit properties from their parents other than setting those properties to a specific value.

You can exclude an element from a selector, but then you have to do that for each variant of that selector:

```
a:not(#epLogin):hover,
a:not(#epLogin):active,
a:not(#epLogin):focus,
#Mainbody div.tags a:not(#epLogin):hover,
#Mainbody a:not(#epLogin)
```

But I wouldn't do that. It's much simpler to set a property to a basic value again. Especially when using a CSS preprocessor. For example:

```
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
    color: #3498db;
}

#epLogin a:hover, #epLogin a:active, #epLogin a:focus {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: +1 although the very last rule should be `a#epLogin:hover, ...` etc.